# Javascript function innerHTML not styled correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to update some HTML using javascript in a webapp that uses JQuery mobile.
For some reason, I can not use the `innerHTML` attribute to create a JQuery Mobile button.
For example:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML + '<p><em>' + var1 + '</em>:<br />' + var2+'</p>';
```

works and gets styled correctly but:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="appendButton()" data-role="button">' + var1 + '</a>';
```

does not. I should say that the `someDiv` is enclosed within a `<div data-role="controlgroup">` if that would make any difference. Also, there are other buttons on the page that work fine.

Why doesn't this work and how can I make it work?

EDIT: I am compiling this into a native app using PhoneGap if that makes any difference...

Comment: Why are you using "document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML" why not "$('#elementId').html()"

Comment: Isn't it just another way to access the same content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the pageCreate event so that jQuery Mobile knows to re-style the element that you just added.

```
$("#someDiv").trigger("create")
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However that doesn't seem to have any effect. Am I using it correctly? `document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="appendButton()" data-role="button">' + var1 + '</a>'; $("#someDiv").trigger("create");`

Comment: Would there be any reason that would not work after compiling into a native iOS application with PhoneGap?

Comment: I don't know, I honestly don't do very much mobile development.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. My problem was that I was using the version of `jquery mobile` that shipped with Dreamweaver 5.5 (`jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js`) rather than the latest version (`jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js`). After the update, it works flawlessy.

Answer (score 1):

When adding elements that have special functionality, it is important to re-run the initialisation of said functionality.

For this purpose, I like to define a `dom_mods()` function that does exactly that. So, whenever I add content to the page, I simply call `dom_mods()` and all my special features are run or updated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to append an element to the `div`.

```
var div = document.getElementById('someDiv'),
    anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute('href', '#');
anchor.addEventListener('click', appendButton, false);
anchor.setAttribute('data-role', 'button');
anchor.innerHTML = var1;
div.appendChild(anchor);
```

Let me know if you have any questions.